# Will the loop be blocked for a callback function in winpcap?

Tags: c++, networking, winsock, winpcap

In winpcap C++ environmet.

```
pcap_loop(adhandle, 0, packet_handler, NULL);
```

packet_handler is a callback function when it receives a packet.

Now my problem is

If I wrote a code like this

```
while(true)
 {
     pcap_loop(adhandle,0, packet_handler,NULL);
}
```

Could it happen that the pcap_loop function will be executed twice or more before the resend function being callbacked?

Or the loop will be blocked until the callback function finished to continue?

Comment: As for your problem, my understanding is that `pcap_loop` will not return until it's done. So then no, the loop will stop at the `pcap_loop` call, and not continue until `pcap_loop` returns, which means there will only be one `pcap_loop` active at a time.

Comment: Sorry,I mistakenly add parentheses to it, it is just a callback function as I said.

Comment: Because the callback function is just a pointer to a function just like other parameter?

Comment: It's easy to test though: Add some output before and after the `pcap_loop` call (remember to flush the output to make sure it's written immediately).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback is called synchronously - `pcap_loop` won't process the next packet until the callback is completed.

Furthermore, `pcap_loop` (with `cnt = 0`) itself just runs in its own infinite loop, until you call `pcap_breakloop` somewhere.  It therefore makes little sense to enclose the call to `pcap_loop` within your own `while (true)` loop.

The corollary of that is that `pcap_loop` itself is a blocking synchronous function.  Therefore in a Windows UI environment then unless your `pcap_loop` is contained within its own thread you should consider just calling `pcap_next` (or `pcap_next_ex`) within the main application event loop, so as not to block the UI thread.

Comment: Thank you.And if `pcap_loop` is an infinite loop, can I use two `pcap_loop` function in one thread?

Comment: @kururu that wouldn't make sense - they can't both run simultaneously. Wondering why you'd want to...

Comment: I want to transfer data between net cards,like a router software.And each net card will have its own pcat_t handle.May be it is not the best way to do it.

Comment: @kururu assuming that you're using `libpcap` to obtain raw ethernet frames, ideally you'd use one thread per card. I presume you're going to use some non-pcap-based method to write the frames out on the other card?

Comment: That would be too difficult for me.I just use the `pcap_sendpacket` function to send raw packet to the ethernet.It is just a course design not for actually use , may be I can just use `pcap_next_ex` instead because there won't be much traffic so the efficiency is not really a problem.

Comment: @kururu ah yes, I forgot about `pcap_sendpacket`.  Note that `pcap_next_ex` is also a blocking function, although I believe it does support a timeout.  "Simultaneous" reading of two separate interfaces from a single thread would require either a very short time out or non-blocking pcap reads.

Comment: Non-blocking pcap reads are done by calling `pcap_setnonblock()`, with a *nonblock* argument of 1, on the `pcap_t`.  However, if you're going to put the `pcap_t` in non-blocking mode, you will probably need to have your code block *somewhere* if you don't want it consuming CPU 100% of the time, so you will need to use `pcap_getevent()` to get a `HANDLE` on which you could do `WaitForSingleObject()`, `WaitForMultipleObjects()`, `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()`, etc..

Comment: Note that if the wait function you call indicates that you can read from the `HANDLE`, and therefore that you can get packets from the `pcap_t` without blocking, you can call `pcap_dispatch()`, which will loop through the packets that are immediately available, but will not block in that loop if you have set non-blocking mode.